# Bluetooth BLE onCharacteristicRead() gives Status= 128

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, android-things, android-ble

When i am trying to read characteristic using `readCharacteristic()` it giving me `true` but when i am getting response in `onCharacteristicRead()` it giving me

> status = 128

instead of

> status=0 (BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS)

Can any one help me or guide me ??
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Android Bluetooth source code status 128 refers to: [GATT_NO RESOURCES](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/bluetooth/bluedroid/+/5738f83aeb59361a0a2eda2460113f6dc9194271/stack/include/gatt_api.h#49)

I'd encourage you to share more code as this error code should only appear if you haven't defined your BluetoothGattCharacteristic / BluetoothGattDescriptor.

Comment: Thanks for response. I have added my descriptor and it giving me success in writedescriptor(). and FYI , i am using descriptor for different characteristic.

Comment: final UUID CHARACTERISTIC_UPDATE_NOTIFICATION_DESCRIPTOR_UUID = UUID
                .fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

        mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(rx_characteristic, true);

        readDescriptor = rx_characteristic
                .getDescriptor(CHARACTERISTIC_UPDATE_NOTIFICATION_DESCRIPTOR_UUID);
if (readDescriptor == null) {
            return false;
        }
readDescriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE); and writing descriptor when my all characteristic read completd

Comment: No i am not writing and reading same characteristic. I am writing in another characteristic which causing status change and it giving me 128 while reading that status changed characteristic. 

one major noticeable thing is that without requestmtu()  its working properly